# Exporting code style settings from IntelliJ IDEA version 14.1.5

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, intellij-14, code-standards

I'm using the updated version of the IntelliJ IDEA and am trying to export my code style settings so that they can be used by all developers working on a particular project. I read the tutorials at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Code+Styles and http://forum.shakacode.com/t/sharing-your-intellij-rubymine-webstorm-codestyle-among-developers/240, which seems fairly simple.

Unfortunately that is not how my 'export settings' pane looks like, and I don't have a line that says 'code styles'. Mine looks like [image: intellij export settings]

The closest I can find is the line I highlighted which has CodeStyleSettingsManager in it along with a whole bunch of other stuff. However I tried using that and extracted the .jar file only to find that there was nothing much inside at all.

Does anyone know a way of exporting code styles that works with the latest version of IntelliJ?

Edit: My codeStyleSettings.xml file only contains the following:

```
<project version="4">
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleSettingsManager">
<option name="PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS">
<value/>
</option>
<option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true"/>
</component>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand, why you don't see `Code Style` in your list (it appears in my IDEA 14.1.5), but...

> (...) export my code style settings so that they can be used by all developers working on a particular project

A better way to share the project code style across all developers is to include it in your VCS repository. Pulling such a commit will apply those code styles automatically. This is the file: `project/.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml`. If your VCS is set to ignore `.idea/`, add an exception for this file.

If you don't see this file at all, you're probably using a local formatter and your `Project` scheme is unchanged. In this case, go to `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Scheme: Manage`, select your formatter and click `Copy to Project`.

**Update**

Code style files only state the difference to the IDEA `Default` Code style (which is always the same). You can try this yourself: create a new project, go the the Code Style settings, select `Project` and change only one option. The `codeStyleSettings.xml` file will be created, and it will contain only this one option. If you could export your code style settings, the output would be exactly the same.

Comment: My codeStyleSettings.xml file only has a few lines, though. Can that really encapsulate all the code style settings? (contents of xml file pasted in opening post)

Comment: Thanks Darek! But what if someone wants to import my code style into, say, Eclipse? Will the code style file work for that as well?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to import IntelliJ code settings into Eclipse. If you want to use the same code styles across different editors/IDEs, try [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/). IntelliJ already supports EditorConfig already, for Eclipse you'll need a plugin.

Comment: But where can those IDEA Default styles be found? Their documentation says "You can define the code styles that differ from the pre-defined ones" (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html). So where are those "pre-defined ones"?

Comment: @JWoodchuck - Open Settings → Editor → Code Style and change "Scheme" to "Default (IDE)" to see all default values.

Comment: Thanks, Darek. But the thing is, those can be changed, correct?

Comment: Further, if I change, say, number of spaces per indent in "Default (IDE)" to 2 and change it in my "project" style also to 2, then when I export my project style settings it still includes that style in the export. I would think it would not include that if the "Default (IDE)" were what it's comparing against (since it supposedly only exports differences).